# how to open google links inside iframe?

Tags: php, iframe

i am trying to open a google search inside an iframe. it was working until recently but something happened.

this can be tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/xTjyX/

i also added `&output=embed` at the end of the link, but it looks like it doesn't help.

in chrome i get: `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`
but it doesn't work in Mozilla also.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Although it probably against Googles T&Cs you could CURL the request and display it through your server

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X-Frame option is a header sent by the webserver of the page you are trying to embed into the iframe. It basically tells the browser not to allow embedding the page in an iframe. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header for a more detailed description.

Obviously Google does not want you to embed it's search results into an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing the same problem - this time with google in a standard frame. It was fine a couple of months ago, now it's not working. I think that Google just changed the rules... *Not* a very open thing to do.

I'd suggest that you run what was in the iframe as a separate child window or new tab - not sure if this will give you the result you wanted.