# Google in iframe

Tags: php, iframe

how can we return the result on the iframe with page filled inside the iframe container.

```
<form action="what.php" method="POST">
<center><input type="text" name="search"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Search google" name="submit">
</center></form>
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$a = '<iframe width="500" height="400" src="http://www.google.com/search?q='.$_POST['search'].'"></iframe>';
echo htmlentities($a);
echo $a;
}
?>
```

overload:auto  didn't worked, 
What can get to display the result of i am feeling lucky through google search on my iframe :) pardon my ignorance if i am asking a silly question

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to display Google Search Results outside of the iFrame?

Comment: Read this 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to open google links inside iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800370/how-to-open-google-links-inside-iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response header you will get "X-Frame-Options : SAMEORIGIN".
checkout this [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

[Some other similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800370/how-to-open-google-links-inside-iframe)