# JQuery problems w/ attr() changing object

Tags: jquery, object

I'm trying to have working JQuery button menu which will change in  attribute data, so will autoreload what's inside object parameter, but it don't want to work :(

The code with CSS, HTML and JQuery is in below link

http://jsbin.com/iqukak/2/edit

Anyone can help?

```
$('button#1').attr("id"){
      $("object#cgi").attr('data','http://www.google.com')};
   $('button#2').attr("id"){
      $("object#cgi").attr('data','http://www.bing.com')};
    $('button#3').attr("id"){
      $("object#cgi").attr('data','http://www.yahoo.com')};
});
```

Update:

I have uploaded all the files to http://szary.eu/panel/
What I want to achive is:
- when I click on 1 i need 1.html inside `<object>` visible
- when I click on 2 I need 2.html inside `<object>` visible

Comment: For the beginning fix your "`</scripst>`" And `object parameter` looks to me like an `object tag`

Comment: What do You mean by object tag?

Comment: What do you expect `$('button#1').attr("id"){...}` to do?

Comment: @muistooshort I wanted to change the <object ... data="http://url"> to be changed when the id=1 is met. But as I see I've made a big mess :-/

http://jsbin.com/iqukak/13/edit It's actual what I've corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button#1').click(function() {
      $("object#cgi").attr('data','http://www.google.com')});
   $('button#2').click(function() {
      $("object#cgi").attr('data','http://www.bing.com')});
    $('button#3').click(function() {
      $("object#cgi").attr('data','http://www.yahoo.com')});
});
```

Although I don't believe Google will let you do this anyway (Bing and Yahoo are fine though)
http://jsbin.com/iqukak/15/edit

See this question for why it wont work with Google: [how to open google links inside iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800370/how-to-open-google-links-inside-iframe)

Comment: i've tried your link and it works for Bing and Yahoo. Google will not work - they won't allow it

Comment: Hm, I've tried that in Google Chrome @ Windows and it wasn't working, but under Firefox @ Linux it's working ...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324108/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url Chrome itself is blocking the request because it views it as being unsafe

Comment: do You know how I can achieve what I want in google chrome? Because it's starting to be a little frustrating that I can't embed a html site (or rather cgi script will be the destination) inside my html site :-/ @Beno

Comment: @SebastianSzary you can try use an iframe instead. see here: http://jsbin.com/iqukak/20/edit

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

    $('td.mleft button').click(function(){
      $('#cgi').attr( 'data',   'http://'+ $(this).text().toLowerCase() +'.com' );  
    });

});
```

And btw: google will never show up and for example if you point to stackoverflow you will be rerouted. So think twice what are you trying to achieve:
cause to prevent *"clickjacking"*, they're sending a HTTP response header called "X-Frame-Options" to prevent pages to be "framed"

**EDIT** 
I would discourage you from using `<object>` tag for that purpose,
use `.load()` instead:

```
$('#cgi').load( $(this).text() +'.html');
```

Comment: To be honest I want to have working JQuery button menu to change internal pages inside <object>. The Google, Yahoo and Bing were just examples.

Comment: you really don't need two jquery libraries: remove `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">` and wrap your code into document ready.

Comment: Corrected. You can refresh index.html

Comment: thank You, I have accepted the answer.
But still it's not working in Google Chrome for me :(

Comment: I would highly discourage you from using `object` for that purpose, use the jQuery .load('url') and load your content inside a standard `<div>` element.